# Bypass DS-Lite via reverse SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunnel

My ISP unfortunately only provides a DS-Lite connection (no IPv4 address, only a IPv6 address) which makes it impossible to create IPv4 port forwardings to access devices in my local network.

But I have a vServer with an IPv4+IPv6 address and a user (non-root) shell. So I thought it would be possible to make a SSH tunnel from a raspberry pi in my local network to the vServer. And then to create a IP forwarding from the raspberry pi to the device I would like to reach in my local network. Is that in general possible? Can I initiate the tunnel from the raspberry pi or must it be initiated by the vServer to the raspberry pi?

Temporarily I created a webserver on the raspberry pi (on port 64321) and I tried the command:

```
ssh -R 64321:localhost:64321 user@tunnelserver.com
```

But I could not reach the webserver by entering `tunnelserver.com:6421`.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Performance will probably be a lot better with a VPN tunnel. Resiliency is probably also a concern.

Comment: A VPN Tunnel is not an option because of the user account restrictions. What do you mean by resiliency in regard of SSH?

Comment: Which protocols do you need to have working from outside?

Comment: HTTP and SSH would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don’t have admin access to the VPS, correct? That will keep you from implementing more efficient solutions.

I’m going to point out two obvious mistakes here:

- You missed a digit in the port: `64321` in the `ssh` command line, but `6421` when trying.
- Because you didn’t specify a `bind_address` (as in `-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport`), the remote port is listening at `localhost`. You need to use either `0.0.0.0`, `[::]` or `\*` to make it listen on all interfaces.

Also, to make this work at all, the `GatewayPorts` directive in `sshd_config` (the OpenSSH server configuration file) needs to be set to `yes` or `clientspecified` (better). The default value is of course `no`.

If you make it work, there’s no need for port forwarding. Simple specify the correct target host and port in the `-R` parameter.

Comment: Yes, its not a real vServer more like an "extended webhosting". I just had to add an additional port rule to the firewall and now it works like you described. Thank you very much!
For the future - what would be a more efficient solution? A VPN?

Comment: Yeah, a VPN connection is actually made to transport network data. With SSH, it’s just a byproduct, so there may be performance limitations, both in throughput and latency. With VPN, you could set up port forwards directly on the VPS. Of course it’s a little tricky to get the routing right.